# Абсолютное позиционирование и @media

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

Добрый  день!
Столкнулся с проблемой абсолютного позиционирования для media запросов

### Для адаптивного дизайна предусмотрены такие вот блоки: [image: Мобильный дизайн]

Я вырезал картинки без текста и кнопок,  текст и кнопки  я разместил абсолютно, поверх  `img`, естественно  при уменьшении окна браузера пропорции картинки уменьшаются и все абсолютные элементы уплывают  в разные стороны и это становится очень некрасиво.  я  так понимаю  я пошел не той  дорогой.
В html это выглядит вот так:

```html
<div class="mob1 mob_box2">
  <img src="img/mob2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <p>PCI DSS 3.2 Avenue</p>
  <button>Learn more </button>
</div>
```

Как я  уже понял,  я  пошел  не той дорогой...
Прошу подсказать, как  лучше реализовать  live text  поверх такого фона и стоит ли отдельно нарезать иконки?

Comment: какой дорогой вы пошли не понятно, выложите свой код, чтобы было понятно что править, что подсказать

Comment: [mcve] - создайте со стилями с html